Why is Jacob described as being 'hired' to be slept with? (Genesis 30:16)

14 In the days of wheat harvest Reuben went and found mandrakes in the
field and brought them to his mother Leah. Then Rachel said to Leah,
“Please give me some of your son's mandrakes.” 15 But she said to her,
“Is it a small matter that you have taken away my husband? Would you
take away my son's mandrakes also?” Rachel said, “Then he may lie with
you tonight in exchange for your son's mandrakes.” 16 When Jacob came
from the field in the evening, Leah went out to meet him and said,
“You must come in to me, for I have hired you with my son's
mandrakes.” So he lay with her that night.

Leah is obviously Jacob's wife, though the less loved of the two. Leah, as Jacob’s wife, shouldn't normally need to "hire" him to sleep with her. Leah had already borne Jacob many sons. Not only that, but Jacob himself wasn't really "paid" anything.
Why then is Jacob described as being 'hired'?

This incident is one of the best arguments against polygamy because it shows the kind of absurd debates/arguments/bargaining that develops between rival wives.  I suspect that this is the reason it is included - to show that polygamy is based on a fundamental flaw of divided affection.

She is joking. She is teasing her husband, as wives are apparently prone to do.
The premise behind the claim is that Jacob has become the servant of Rachel in sexual matters. So by "paying" the mandrake to Rachel, Leah has "hired his services" from his mistress. As one might hire the services of a slave by paying his master.
I now formally renounce my previous opinion that "Don't start quarrelling on the way back" (Genesis ch45 v24) is the first joke recorded in the Bible. This one is obviously much earlier.

Rachel initiated the transaction, so Rachel makes the joke?

An interesting question. Perhaps the dynamic is that Rachel picks up and gives a lighter twist to Leah's bitter comparison of the two "losses".

Besides joking, there may be another possibility. Rachel made a deal with Leah that she could sleep with Jacob in exchange for the mandrakes, suggesting that Jacob had not been sleeping with Leah for quite some time. Otherwise, the deal would not have interested Leah. Subsequently, Leah gave birth to a son of her own, naming him Issachar, a name that sounds like the Hebrew word for "reward", which might be a gratitude to several things;

Her prayer being granted by God (Genesis 30:17)
Reward for giving her servant Zilpah to Jacob (Genesis 30:18), and
Reward from making a good deal with Rachel to earn the opportunity to sleep with Jacob.

It is worth noting that Rachel was struggling with infertility. In biblical times, mandrakes were often associated with fertility and love. Rachel believed that mandrakes could help her conceive, so she traded a night with Jacob to Leah in exchange for some mandrakes (Ref: christianity.com).
This context explanins why Leah would view this opportunity as a valuable deal; she traded some mandrakes to Rachel for the chance to sleep with Jacob.
Mandrakes - Christianity.com

Haamek Davar, a 19th century commentator, says that the wording here of being "hired out" demonstrates how Jacob related to his wives.
He was in the service of his wives, currently serving Rachel and fulfilling her desires, and now being hired out to serve Leah.   This is in contrast to most men of those days her were masters over their wives and put their wants first.
